# Flexbox vertically align items to the center of navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to make a navbar, and would like its contents vertically aligned in the center. I am using `flex` to do this, but can not get the items to align in the center.

```css
#nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3498db;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}
#nav-container .container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-logo {
  max-height: 35px;
  float: left;
}
ul.navmenu {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
ul.navmenu li {
  padding-right: 25px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">

  <div class="container">

    <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />

    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `height` of the flex container `#nav-container .container` is `auto`, in the other words the height of the containing content, so `align-items` takes no effects visually.

You can set it to `#nav-container .container { height: 100%; }` or `height: inherit;`, since the parent `#nav-container` has fixed height.

```css
#nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3498db;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}
#nav-container .container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%; /*added*/
}
.top-nav-logo {
  max-height: 35px;
  float: left;
}
ul.navmenu {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
ul.navmenu li {
  padding-right: 25px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">

  <div class="container">

    <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />

    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</header>
```

Otherwise, you can use nested flexbox, make the `#nav-container` as a flex container, and have `#nav-container .container` as a flex item.

```css
#nav-container .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
#nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3498db;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex; /*added*/
  align-items: center; /*added*/
}
#nav-container .container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-logo {
  max-height: 35px;
  float: left;
}
ul.navmenu {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
ul.navmenu li {
  padding-right: 25px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">

  <div class="container">

    <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />

    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, just set the height on `#nav-container .container`.

```css
#nav-container {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #3498db;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
}
#nav-container .container {
max-width: 800px;
position: relative;
padding: 0 30px;
height: 50px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-logo {
max-height: 35px;
float: left;
}
ul.navmenu {
margin: 0 0 0 50px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
ul.navmenu li {
padding-right: 25px;
display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />
    
    <ul class="navmenu"><li>Home</li><li>About</li><li>Contact</li></ul>
  
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `#nav-container` (in addition to your current settings):

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

This centers the `.container` inside `#nav-container`

```css
#nav-container {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #3498db;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
#nav-container .container {
max-width: 800px;
position: relative;
padding: 0 30px;

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-logo {
max-height: 35px;
float: left;
}
ul.navmenu {
margin: 0 0 0 50px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
ul.navmenu li {
padding-right: 25px;
display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />
    
    <ul class="navmenu"><li>Home</li><li>About</li><li>Contact</li></ul>
  
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only prop you need to add is `display: flex;` to `#nav-container`.

In fact, this is the only change I did to your code.

```css
#nav-container {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #3498db;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
display: flex; 
}
#nav-container .container {
max-width: 800px;
position: relative;
padding: 0 30px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-logo {
max-height: 35px;
float: left;
}
ul.navmenu {
margin: 0 0 0 50px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
ul.navmenu li {
padding-right: 25px;
display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />
    
    <ul class="navmenu"><li>Home</li><li>About</li><li>Contact</li></ul>
  
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the container inside #nav-container fill its height.

```
#nav-container .container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cjrqjwav/

Answer (score 0):

The element `#nav-container` needs to be a flex-container as well.

I recommend wrapping your image in another element for example a `div` to prevent any undesired behavior when it becomes a flex-item.

You can also do some cleanup by removing all the unnecessary floats and make your `ul` element a flex-container.

```css
#nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3498db;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex; /* Make parent container a flex-container as well*/
}
#nav-container .container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.top-nav-logo {
  max-height: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Use this instead of float: left; */
}
ul.navmenu {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removed unnecessary float: left;*/
  list-style-type: none; /* Remove ul marker */
  display: flex; /* Make unordered list a flex-container */
  align-items: center; /* Align list items vertically */
}
ul.navmenu li {
  padding-right: 25px;
  /* Removed unncessary display property for flex-items */
}
```

```html
<header id="nav-container">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="My Site" class="top-nav-logo" />
    </div>
    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</header>
```